# Maintaining scroll position in ListViews without nested scroll controllers

Tags: flutter

I'm using a `NestedScrollView` with a `SliverAppBar` to implement a collapsing header. Works like a champ! Inside the app bar, I'm also using a `TabBar` so that my header looks like the following:

[image: Collapsible header]

The contents of the `TabBarView`s are instances of `MyListOfThingsWidget` which contain a `ListView` of `Item`s. Fairly standard setup... the problem is that when I switch between the tabs, the `ListView`s are not maintaining their own scroll offset. ie. if I scroll down a page on the **Featured** tab, when I switch to the **Nearby** tab, it has already scrolled. I want each `ListView` to maintain their own scroll offset.

I can achieve this by setting each `ListView.controller` property to an instance of `ScrollController` in `MyListOfThingsWidget`... however, that breaks my collapsing header logic because I've now got nested `ScrollController`s inside a `NestedScrollView`.

I've tried setting a different `key` on each `ListView` but that didn't change anything.

Is there a way to get the `ListView`s to maintain their own scroll position without having nested scroll controllers?